# How do I have two sets of page numbers in a document?

Tags: page-numbering, lastpage

I want to have two sets of page numbers (P and p) in my document. The first one (P)  is global, the second one (p) resets to 1 at some predefined points.

So, the document will look like,

Text

P1/5         p1/3

Text

P2/5         p2/3

Text

P3/5         p3/3

Text. *In this page the page number (p, second one) is reset.*

P4/5         p1/2

Text

P5/5         p2/2

To get the total page count a label in the last page or the lastpage package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) can help me. And that is not the subject of this question.

The problem is with the second counter. I can use chappg (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chappg) with noauto option. But I loose the global page counter P. Moreover, the (sub) total number of pages in that group has to be manually set.

I understand that if I write a set of macros with a new counter (my@local@page), reset it at my predefined points, label the last page in a group (label names will have to be distinct), perhaps I can achieve my goal. But that requires at least half a day. Which I do not have at this moment.

I was wondering if you can suggest something readily usable.

Comment: What defines this group of sub-pages? Is it a chapter? A section? Also, what `\documentclass` are you using? Do you have any package restrictions?

Comment: This is actually a list where I need to reset the page number for a new group. These points are known to me (i.e. I can manually issue a command there, but nothing automatic). These are not chapters or sections or anything like that.
\documentclass is article. No package restrictions.

Comment: Is a `\newpage` or `\clearpage` issued before the command that changes the page numbering? If so, it would make things much easier.

Comment: Yes, \clearpage is always issued the changes in page numbering.

Comment: If you are ready to compile separately the separately-numbered page groups, the `pdfpage` package might help you.

Comment: pdfpages is one of my favorite packages, but the separate groups are too many (around 150) to be handled in this manner. Then I will have to resort to a shell script. 
May be writing the macros I proposed will mean the same degree of involvement for me.

Comment: Maybe a look at the footer in the example of the http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts package could be helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a possible setup. I use `fancyhdr` for typesetting the two page numbers and also for stepping the secondary counter. The macro `\resetpageaux` does a `\clearpage`, sets a label and sets the secondary counter to zero. At the end of the document we set also the last label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\twopagenumbers}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\twopagenumbers}
}

\usepackage{atenddvi}
\usepackage[user]{zref}

\newcounter{pageaux}
\def\currentauxref{PAGEAUX1}
\newcommand{\twopagenumbers}{%
  \stepcounter{pageaux}%
  P \thepage/\zpageref{LastPage} -- p \thepageaux/\ref{\currentauxref}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetpageaux}{%
  \clearpage
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thepageaux}\label{\currentauxref}%
  \xdef\currentauxref{PAGEAUX\thepage}%
  \setcounter{pageaux}{0}}
\AtEndDvi{\edef\@currentlabel{\thepageaux}\label{\currentauxref}}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for mock text

\begin{document}

\kant

\resetpageaux

\kant[1-14]

\resetpageaux

\kant[1-22]

\end{document}
```

[image]