# Is there any package that supports multiple last pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, lastpage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I have two sets of page numbers in a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82520/how-do-i-have-two-sets-of-page-numbers-in-a-document)

I am trying to make one single file that contains several small components. Each small parts need its own last page. For example, if I have two parts and they have 3 pages and 5 pages, respectively, then I want to have page numbers like

```
*1 of 3, 2 of 3, 3 of 3, 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5, 4 of 5 and 5 of 5*
```

I tried with `lastpage` and `fancyhdr`. And use the following setting

```
*\fancyhead[R]{\thepage of \pageref{LastPage}}*
```

And it is giving me only the last last page and the results looks like

```
*1 of **5**, 2 of **5**, 3 of **5**, 1 of 5, 2 of 5, 3 of 5, 4 of 5 and 5 of 5*
```

I think maybe there is some way to have what I want if I use the `ifthen` package also. However, I cannot figure it out by myself.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This seems at least similar to [How do i have two sets of page numbers in a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82520/how-do-i-have-two-sets-of-page-numbers-in-a-document).

Comment: @egreg I added the [tag:lastpage] tag to the linked question.

Comment: +1 because the possible original question was hard to find.