# Reset page numbering and total number of pages per section

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

This question is similar to: [How do I have two sets of page numbers in a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82520/how-do-i-have-two-sets-of-page-numbers-in-a-document)

I have an `exam` class document (built on `article`) that contains the exam questions in a first `section*` and extra output/figures in a second `section*`. Both are in the same document in order to be able to refer to the correct labels using `ref{}`. Yet, both sections will be printed separately and should contain page numbers like `page 3 of 12`.

I use `fancyhdr` to get that footer correctly, but I have a problem getting the correct `numpages`. Now it counts only the number of pages for the last section (in this case 2). I've been playing with the solution given in the question I link to, but I was hoping there was a simpler solution.

Example :

```
\documentclass{exam}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    % Get rid of verticalmode errors from exam class
}
% From the cls file we use for the exams
\AtBeginDocument{
    \pagestyle{foot}
    \footer{}{Page \thepage\ / \numpages}{}
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % get some text

\begin{document}

You have \numpages~pages

\kant[1-14]

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Another section}

You have \numpages~pages

\kant[1-7]  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to show then explain.  `\label` stores the counter and page from the last `\refstepcounter`, hence the dummy counter.  There are other ways to do this, but they involve `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcounter{dummy}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    % Get rid of verticalmode errors from exam class
}
% From the cls file we use for the exams
\AtBeginDocument{
    \pagestyle{foot}
    \footer{}{Page \thepage\ / \pageref{first}}{}
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % get some text

\begin{document}

You have \pageref{first}~pages

\kant[1-14]

\refstepcounter{dummy}\label{first}% store page number
\clearpage
\footer{}{Page \thepage\ / \numpages}{}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section*{Another section}

You have \numpages~pages

\kant[1-7]  

\end{document}
```

---

You can't mess with `\numpages`, but you can create a new macro (`\secpages`) to replace it.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand{\secpages}{\pageref{first}}
\newcommand{\resetpagecounts}{%
  \refstepcounter{dummy}\label{first}% store page number
  \clearpage
  \let\secpages=\numpages
  \setcounter{page}{1}}


\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    % Get rid of verticalmode errors from exam class
}
% From the cls file we use for the exams
\AtBeginDocument{
    \pagestyle{foot}
    \footer{}{Page \thepage\ / \secpages}{}
}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % get some text

\begin{document}

You have \secpages~pages

\kant[1-14]

\resetpagecounts
\section*{Another section}

You have \secpages~pages

\kant[1-7]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a neat way of working around it. It solves my problem for now, but ultimately I should get this into the cls file so my colleagues can simply insert `\resetpagecounts` to get the correct result. I got things working more or less based on the `zref` and `atenddvi` trick from the other question, but it still feels overly complicated. If you have a more concise solution that could fit in a cls, feel free to add it.

Comment: Thanks again, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @john Kormylo I did that and I lose the total number of pages of the document, that I also need. could you please help me? I need to have something like A1/50, so I need the page inside sections and the total number. I have this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665131/how-to-restart-the-page-numbering-in-each-appendix?noredirect=1#comment1653919_665131) open, can you have a look please?

Comment: @JenifferBarreto - I would be very surprised if something intended for exam class worked for KOMA.