# two page numbering scheme for SOP - Standard Operating Procedure document

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I'm writing several SOP's - Standard Operation Procedure for a cosmetics industry. I need two page numbering scheme in the footer, one with all pages of the document and other with all pages of specific SOP, something like this:

Global Page: 1/180

SOP Page: 1/7

the main TOC must show the global numbering and the TOC of each SOP, the local numbering.

How to do it?

```
\documentclass {article} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{} %clear header and footer
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
    \rfoot{
        \fbox{
            \begin{tabular}{r}
                Global Page: \thepage/\thepage \\
                SOP Page: \thepage/\thepage \\
            \end{tabular}
    }}
}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SOP 1 - Administration}

\pagestyle{firststyle}


\startlist{toc}
\printlist{toc}{}{\section*{Contents - SOP 1}}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{OBJECTIVE}
\section{RESPONSIBILITY}
\section{PROCEDURES}
\stopcontents
\newpage

\setcounter{section}{0}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SOP 2 - Prodution}

\startlist{toc}
\printlist{toc}{}{\section*{Contents - SOP 2}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{OBJECTIVE}
\section{RESPONSIBILITY}
\section{PROCEDURES}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two page counters were defined: the normal page number and a secondary one that is reset before each SOP.

The code for the second  was taken from [two sets of page numbers in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82560/161015)

The total number of physical pages of the document was obtained using the package `lastpage`.

The complete document has a total of 11 pages: SOP 1 (one page) SOP 2 (9 pages) and the ToC (one page).

**SOP 1** : one page long.

[image: a]

**SOP 2** : first page, nine pages long.

[image: b]

The last page of SOP2 and also of the full document.

[image: C]

And the ToC.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{atenddvi} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{lastpage}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[user]{zref}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLY dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \fancyhf{} %clear header and footer
    \fancyfoot[R]{\stepcounter{pageaux}
            \fbox{%
            \begin{tabular}{r}
                Global Page: \thepage/\pageref{LastPage} \\
                SOP Page: \thepageaux/\ref{\currentauxref} \\
        \end{tabular}}
}}
\pagestyle{firststyle}

%%********************************* from  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82560/161015
\newcounter{pageaux}
\def\currentauxref{PAGEAUX1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\resetpageaux}{%
    \clearpage
    \edef\@currentlabel{\thepageaux}\label{\currentauxref}%
    \xdef\currentauxref{PAGEAUX\thepage}%
    \setcounter{pageaux}{0}}
\AtEndDvi{\edef\@currentlabel{\thepageaux}\label{\currentauxref}}
\makeatother
%%*********************************

\begin{document}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}   
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SOP 1 - Administration}
        
    \resetpageaux% reset aux page numbers
    
    \startlist{toc}
    \printlist{toc}{}{\section*{Contents - SOP 1}}
    
    \section{OBJECTIVE}
    \kant[9]
    \section{RESPONSIBILITY}
    \kant[2]
    \section{PROCEDURES}
    \kant[9]
    \stopcontents
    
    \newpage
    
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SOP 2 - Production}
    
    \resetpageaux% reset aux page numbers
    
    \startlist{toc}
    \printlist{toc}{}{\section*{Contents - SOP 2}}
    
    \section{OBJECTIVE}
    \kant[1-8]
    \section{RESPONSIBILITY}
    \kant[1-8]
    \section{PROCEDURES}
    \kant[1-8]
    \stopcontents
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way for the main TOC to show a global numbering and the TOC of each SOP a local numbering?

Comment: @leonardo cesar The local  ToC is managed by `titletoc`. It will best if you ask another question on that topic.

Comment: i did it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652670/main-toc-show-global-numbering-and-local-toc-show-local-numbering-scheme